Interpretation Comparison Bayesian Models with Leave-One-Out Cross Validation
I'm currently working on comparing two Bayesian linear models using the brms package in R, with a dataset of 400 participants. The models differ in that one includes an additional predictor M_ars. Below is the R code for both models:
Model without M_ars:
model_pol_sophistication_val <- brm(pol_sophistication ~ spread_val+age+sex+education, 
                                   data = df_pol_sophistication,
                                   chains = 4, iter = 12000, warmup = 2000,
                                   prior = priors, 
                                   save_pars = save_pars(all = TRUE))

Model with M_ars:
model_pol_sophistication_comb <- brm(pol_sophistication ~ spread_val*M_ars+age+sex+education, 
                                    data = df_pol_sophistication,
                                    chains = 4, iter = 12000, warmup = 2000,
                                    prior = priors, 
                                    save_pars = save_pars(all = TRUE))

Here is a description of the posterior distributions of the combined model:
Parameter              |   Median |         95% CI |      pd |          ROPE | % in ROPE |  Rhat |      ESS
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(Intercept)            |    -0.30 | [-0.55, -0.05] |  98.96% | [-0.10, 0.10] |     3.97% | 1.000 | 20536.00
spread_val             |     0.16 | [ 0.08,  0.25] |  99.98% | [-0.10, 0.10] |     5.18% | 1.000 | 62480.00
M_ars                  |     0.17 | [ 0.08,  0.26] | 100.00% | [-0.10, 0.10] |     3.41% | 1.000 | 56197.00
age                    |     0.27 | [ 0.17,  0.38] |    100% | [-0.10, 0.10] |        0% | 1.000 | 45852.00
sexm                   |     0.28 | [ 0.10,  0.47] |  99.87% | [-0.10, 0.10] |     0.33% | 1.000 | 54051.00
educationHBO           |     0.54 | [ 0.23,  0.84] |  99.98% | [-0.10, 0.10] |        0% | 1.000 | 22210.00
educationLagere_School |    -0.12 | [-0.71,  0.47] |  65.84% | [-0.10, 0.10] |    25.76% | 1.000 | 41753.00
educationMBO           |    -0.17 | [-0.46,  0.11] |  88.36% | [-0.10, 0.10] |    29.40% | 1.000 | 20748.00
educationUniversiteit  |     0.71 | [ 0.39,  1.03] |    100% | [-0.10, 0.10] |        0% | 1.000 | 22415.00
educationVMBO          |    -0.31 | [-0.64,  0.03] |  96.53% | [-0.10, 0.10] |     8.96% | 1.000 | 25270.00
spread_val:M_ars       | 5.59e-03 | [-0.06,  0.07] |  56.43% | [-0.10, 0.10] |      100% | 1.000 | 61821.00

This is the result of a Bayesian Model Comparison:
comparison_pol_sophistication <- bayesfactor_models(model_pol_sophistication_val, model_pol_sophistication_comb)
comparison_pol_sophistication
Bayes Factors for Model Comparison
    Model                                        BF
[2] spread_val * M_ars + age + sex + education 2.04

* Against Denominator: [1] spread_val + age + sex + education
*   Bayes Factor Type: marginal likelihoods (bridgesampling)

For assessing predictive accuracy, I performed leave-one-out cross-validation using the loo() function:
loo_pol_sophistication_comb <- loo(model_pol_sophistication_comb)
loo_pol_sophistication_val <- loo(model_pol_sophistication_val, K = 10, chains = 4)
compare<-loo_compare(loo_pol_sophistication_comb, loo_pol_sophistication_val)
print(compare, simplify = FALSE, digits = 3)
                              elpd_diff se_diff  elpd_loo se_elpd_loo p_loo    se_p_loo looic    se_looic
model_pol_sophistication_comb    0.000     0.000 -504.605   13.271      11.396    1.124 1009.211   26.543
model_pol_sophistication_val    -5.327     3.746 -509.932   13.190       9.543    0.895 1019.865   26.379

The output showed a minimal elpd_diff of -5.327 with a standard error of 3.746, indicating a slight edge for the combined model but with substantial uncertainty.
I am struggling to interpret this result, particularly in the context of the magnitude of the gain in predictive accuracy and how to evaluate it given the large standard error relative to the difference. Should the slight improvement in elpd_loo warrant the additional complexity from including M_ars in the model? How should I proceed to decide between these models given the results?
Given this context and the Bayesian framework of my analyses, frequentist approaches like computing a confidence interval to test for statistical significance don't seem to fit my other analyses.
Any insights, additional diagnostic suggestions, or relevant experiences would be greatly appreciated!
Here are some sources that I have looked into, but that weren't particularly helpful:
Piironen, J., Vehtari, A. Comparison of Bayesian predictive methods for model selection. Stat Comput 27, 711–735 (2017). https://doi.org/10.1007/s11222-016-9649-y
Sivula, T., Magnusson, M., Matamoros, A. A., & Vehtari, A. (2020). Uncertainty in Bayesian leave-one-out cross-validation based model comparison. arXiv preprint arXiv:2008.10296.https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2008.10296
Vehtari, A., Gelman, A. & Gabry, J. Practical Bayesian model evaluation using leave-one-out cross-validation and WAIC. Stat Comput 27, 1413–1432 (2017). https://doi.org/10.1007/s11222-016-9696-4

Have you considered looking at the bayes factor? The models are nested, so it seems like a very natural choice.
